# Why moving the synchronous code to loop.run_in_executor resulted in decreased performance when tested on blazemeter

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, performance, python-asyncio, sanic

I'm using

- Python-3.7
- sanic-19.3
- asyncio-3.4
- pandas-0.24

I have few pandas operations in my application running on sanic framework.
for example:

```
pandas.merge(df1, df2, on='column_name', how='left')
df.sort_values(['column_name'], ascending=[False])
df.drop('column_name',1)
pandas.read_sql(query, pyodbc_connection)
```

I've tried to move them to run_in_executor as suggested in asyncio documentation.

```
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

await loop.run_in_executor(None,functools.partial(pandas.merge, left=df1, right=df2, on='column_name', how='left'))

await loop.run_in_executor(None, functools.partial(df.sort_values, by=['column_name'],ascending=[False]))

await loop.run_in_executor(None,pandas.read_sql,query,pyodbc_connection)
```

but I saw the overall performance (measured in hits/sec, avg. response time) decrease when tested on [blazemeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/)
Tested with 50 concurrent virtual users, 5mins

Api tested contains many operations including and similar to what is mentioned above (also including the DB calls)

- hits/sec -> around 12% decreased
- avg response time -> around 12-13% increase
- bandwidth -> around 12% decrease

[Before adding loop.run_in_executor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LqByj.png)

[After adding loop.run_in_executor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zweFu.png)

one thing to note is I'm calling `loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()` in every function, instead of calling it in the controller function and passing to every helper function, does that explain the performance hit?

Let me know if any more information is required
Thanks

Comment: How long does each function take to execute? On my machine each call to `run_in_executor` introduces a 0.18ms latency, which is non-negligible. If your functions take much less than that amount, they will certainly be slowed down by the introduced latency, especially since you have added three calls to `run_in_executor` in a row. If nothing else, you can try to replace those three calls with a single call and see if that improves things.

Comment: Please, consider to provide [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Dataframe's merge and sort operations are CPU bound, not IO bound, so they won't gain any perf increase when are run on a _threaded_ executor (and if your CPU utilization is 100%, even multiprocess executor won't bring any speed up), but you will waste resources on the additional overhead to pass tasks to threads and thread-switches. read_sql is a partially IO bound task so it may be beneficial to run it asynchronously on an executor.

Comment: @Fian That explains why it took a performance hit. Thanks. Any suggestions on how can I improve the performance if I have a lot of pandas operation and 2-3 database calls in each API?

Comment: @user4815162342 Thanks for information around added latency, I thought it'd be negligible. I've only given an example of what operations I'm using, there are more than three calls and in different functions

Comment: For low-latency functions you could simply choose to execute them in the asyncio thread. The downside is that during the time they execute, the rest of your application will be unresponsive - but if they take a very small time, then that's ok. You could also take a hybrid approach and choose whether to await `run_in_executor` or run the function in-line based on the amount of data to process.

Comment: In the long run, you could look into [`uvloop`](https://github.com/MagicStack/uvloop), which provides a much more efficient plug-in replacement for the asyncio event loop, and whose `run_in_executor` might be better optimized. You might also want to submit a bugs.python.org issue about the efficiency of stock `run_in_executor`, as 0.18ms seems too much to use comfortably.